# group by and count with linq vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, count, group-by

I have a datatable. I would like to list the double entries. This would I make with a simple sql query like this:

```
SELECT artnr, COUNT(artnr) AS cnt FROM table GROUP BY artnr HAVING COUNT(artnr)>1
```

How should this looke with linq?

Every time, when I need to work with linq, I get always stuck with it. I dislike it really.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what your table looks like, but give this a try. 
Also I'm sure there are plenty of answers on stack that illustrate grouping in VB.
This might be a duplicate question.

```
Dim artnrGroups = From a In table _
                    Group a By Key = a.artnr Into Group _
                    Where Group.Count() > 1
                    Select artnr = Key, numbersCount = Group.Count()
```

Answer (score 1):

And you can put the Count() into that query like this

```
Dim duplicateRows = From row In table _
           Group row By row.artnr Into g _
           Where g.Count() > 1 _
           Select row
```